# Err command Eval on Django channels

Tags: django, web, websocket, redis, channel

I am trying to start Django channels and it needs redis .so I installed it but now it's been giving me an error and that is 
'ERROR UNKNOWN COMMAND EVAL'
I know this has been asked before I am getting some really weird stuff. I have installed redis version 4.6 with my Ubuntu terminal. I start the server there .it still shows me this error.before some days I was using the redid 3.0zip and that used to work fine but today that gives me error also. I don't know what is my problem or where is it.so please if there's any solution to it write down.

Comment: Delete all and re install with `sudo apt-get install redis-server`

Comment: I have some other redis versions installed .I think maybe that's causing the issues.i will delete everything and the see what happens.

Comment: Run `INFO server` to verify the redis version and executable path. Most likely it is running an older version. You may need to use the full path when launching redis-server depending on your system environment configuration to get the one you want up and running

Comment: Hey man I did a silly mistake.actually k have different versions of redis on my system and there was a lower version running in background.i uninstalled it and now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really complicated here.maybe you wo and be having different versions of redis in your PC .maybe a lower version is running in background that's causing all the problem.